# Subscribe to a property of a service from another component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a property `loggedIn` on my authentication service that I need to be subscribed to by a few other services, how can I return an observable to let the other components subscribe to the property?

```
loggedIn: boolean;

// ...

loggedIn(): Observable<boolean>  {
    // ?
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 2):

```
loggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

loggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
 return this.loggedIn;
}
```

The init value of being logged in is false. When you sign in, you need to call `loggedIn.next(true)` on it.